# CSS display:inline-block differs from local to remote view on IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

Good morning Pals.

I have been developing a website and testing in all browsers. As i finished uploading the files to the remote server, the page all renders in IE7 but the horizontal navigation bar which contains a css property display: inline-block. Even though i see this problem viewing through the remote server, locally it's working properly on the same navigator. At first i thought it could be syntax problem or maybe encoding issues, but so far i couldn't find the problem. You all can see the page http://www.retvbrazil.tv

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

IE7 doesn't support `inline-block` so it shouldn't be working in any view. You can use the following hack to get the same effect in IE7.

```
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
```

However since this is just a hack it doesn't work as expected under all conditions so it might need other changes. It might be easier for you to float your elements instead.

Comment: ok... thank you for your reply. locally its working great. http://i40.tinypic.com/bev8yo.png my ie is behaving wrong only in this website. it's totally unreliable. Thank you

Comment: Yes, IE7 is not a very good browser. IE8 is better. IE9 is even better still. Maybe one day, IE will be a good browser.

Comment: as a matter of fact, it stopped from work locally right now. it's too buggy!

Answer (score 0):

IE7 doesn't support `inline-block`, use `float:left` instead.